# Database design scenario for budget (whole and daily)

Tags: database, database-design

**Scenario**: Each user add funds to his account, for example 100 USD, and he defines that the system (our website) could spend up-to 10 USD per day for showing his ads in the website. each time his ad is shown in or website, it's gonna cost him 1 USD.

**P.S**: we're not inserting a record into the database every time his ad is shown, we just `deduct` the amount for showing his ad (`1 USD`) from his whole budget.

because we're showing too many ads, it's not possible to insert a record for each ad show into the database.

I have 2 columns in users table, `whole_budget` and `daily_budget`, so for the above user `whole_budget` is `100` and `daily_budget` is `10`.

in the above scenario, how can we manage `daily budget`? so when an ad is shown, how we're gonna deduct 1 USD from his account?

how can we know if he has left daily budget? so we can decide to show his ad for the rest of the day or not.

I would appreciate your help

Comment: I think inserting a record for each time you show an ad is going to be much faster than calculating all your business logic every time you show an ad...

Comment: @NevilleK really? even if we're inserting `1M` records per day!!?

Comment: Without a lot more detail, yes - it's (generally) faster to insert a record than to find the customer record, execute whatever business logic, and then update that customer record.